# Reinforcement Learning-TD learning from afterstates

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference

I'm making a program that teaches 2 players to play a simple board game using Reinforcement Learning and the Temporal Difference learning method (TD(λ) ) based on afterstates. Learning occurs by training a neural network. I use [Sutton's NonLinear TD/Backprop neural network](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/td-backprop-pseudo-code.text) ) I would really like your opinion on my following dilemma .
The basic algorithm/pseudo code for playing a turn between the two opponents is this

```
WHITE.CHOOSE_ACTION(GAME_STATE); //White player decides on its next move by evaluating the current game state ( TD(λ) learning)

GAME_STATE = WORLD.APPLY(WHITE_PLAYERS_ACTION);  //We apply the chosen action of the player to the environment and a new game state emerges

 IF (GAME STATE != FINAL ){ // If the new state is not final (not a winning state for white player), do the same for the Black player

    BLACK.CHOOSE_ACTION(GAME_STATE)

GAME_STATE = WORLD.APPLY(BLACK_PLAYERS_ACTION) // We apply the chosen action of the black player to the environment and a new game state emerges.
}
```

When should each player invoke his learning method PLAYER.LEARN(GAME_STATE). Here is the dillema.

OPTION A.
Immediately after each player's move, after the new afterstate emerges, as follows:

```
WHITE.CHOOSE_ACTION(GAME_STATE);
GAME_STATE = WORLD.APPLY(WHITE_PLAYERS_ACTION);
WHITE.LEARN(GAME_STATE)    // White learns from the afterstate that emerged right after his action
IF (GAME STATE != FINAL ){
    BLACK.CHOOSE_ACTION(GAME_STATE)
    GAME_STATE = WORLD.APPLY(BLACK_PLAYERS_ACTION)
    BLACK.LEARN(GAME_STATE) // Black learns from the afterstate that emerged right after his action
```

OPTION B.
Immediately after each player's move, after the new afterstate emerges, but also after the opponents move, if the opponent makes a winning move.

```
WHITE.CHOOSE_ACTION(GAME_STATE);
GAME_STATE = WORLD.APPLY(WHITE_PLAYERS_ACTION);
WHITE.LEARN(GAME_STATE)
IF (GAME_STATE == FINAL ) //If white player won
    BLACK.LEARN(GAME_STATE) // Make the Black player learn from the White player's winning afterstate
IF (GAME STATE != FINAL ){ //If white player's move did not produce a winning/final afterstate
    BLACK.CHOOSE_ACTION(GAME_STATE)
    GAME_STATE = WORLD.APPLY(BLACK_PLAYERS_ACTION)
    BLACK.LEARN(GAME_STATE)
    IF (GAME_STATE == FINAL) //If Black player won
        WHITE.LEARN(GAME_STATE) //Make the White player learn from the Black player's winning afterstate
```

I believe that option B is more reasonable.

Comment: Check [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/24816/2444) if you are interested in details about afterstates.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, with TD learning, an agent would have 3 functions:

- start(observation) → action
- step(observation, reward) → action
- finish(reward)

Action is combined with learning, and a bit more learning also occurs when the game ends.